# Unit testing in Android apps. How should I go about it?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps).

But, there are just too many examples. What is the industry following? What are the best out there?

Also, is it a better idea writing my own unit tests using JUnit or the learning curve is too big for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many testing tools available in the industry but these are standard tools & methods

1. Robotium
2. Deviceanywhere http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing-automation.html
3. perfecto mobile

here is the android official testing guide link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html

use Junit for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to begin with regular test cases for classes which doesn't dependent on android platform. After that you can test your db classes or something like it with AndroidTestCase or ActivityTestCase classes.

When the unit testing is done you can proceed to UI testing with Robotium.